# C++: How to make some class access it's member by default in its object?

Tags: c++

Lets take the example some of the codes like the following use objects but can access their members directly without using any '.' operator

Eg-1

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  string mystr;
  cout << "What's your name? ";
  getline (cin, mystr);
  cout << "Hello " << mystr << ".\n";
  cout << "What is your favorite team? ";
  getline (cin, mystr);
  cout << "I like " << mystr << " too!\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Here mystr is an object of std::string but it can access the group of characters inside it without using the '.' operator it should be

```
getline(cin,mystr.(member_name)); //Here member name is the name of the member which is there inside the class std::string and stores the data
```

But the actual working code is

```
getline(cin,mystr);
```

Second thing what is indirection

Edit 1:

Ok let me put this in a more simpler way if i have some class which has some data members and if i want to use any data member then i need to refer it from the object like

Eg-2

```
class reff{

public:
     int a;
     int b;
}

reff per;
per.a=36;
```

This statement tells that to access any class' members we need to refer it from the object but the same is not happening in the example of std:: string which i have mentioned above mystr is an object so it must be having some data member to store the data if i want to display the data inside a std::string object then i should mention the data member's name along with the objects name but in Eg-1 only object's name is mentioned.

Comment: what member_name? You need to explain this more.

Comment: *Lets take the example some of the codes like the following use objects but can access their members directly without using any '.' operator* What?

Comment: I'm not convinced you are correct about what is happening in your example.  But there is a C++ feature http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator that does nearly what you are requesting:  `operator XXX&() { return m_xxx; }`  That says when the compiler "knows" it needs an `XXX&` (whatever type XXX might be) but instead has this object instead, use member `m_xxx` of this object.  It falls short of what you want (and I think with no possible solution) in cases where you would like the compiler to know it needs an `XXX&` but the compiler fails to know that.

Comment: Is "Second thing what is indirection" a question? Could you consider opening a new question for that instead of asking two things in the same question? BTW https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indirection may be interesting for you to read.

Comment: Implementations of `getline` and `operator <<` would probably use internal of string by using its members.

Comment: @Jarod42 I'm guessing that's the point of the question, but OP should at least try to make their question understandable.

Comment: I want to ask how the compiler knows which member to access when the object's name is used in the code like mystr is an object of std::string but when i use it my code efficiently accesses the data

Comment: Your `string` example is bad because it is not actually an example of what you are describing.  The compiler is **not** selecting the conversion from `string` to array of `char` when it resolves `<<` or `getline`.  But in other cases, the compiler does what you are requesting, as described in my earlier comment.  That only occurs when the `operator` I described is defined in the class, telling the compiler to use a specific member of the object when it needs to pass the object as a different type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the call to `getline(cin,mystr);` does not directly specify any of the members of `mystr` is because the `getline()` function requires a **`string` object**, *not* one of its member variables. The actual implementation will access the individual members, but as a user of the `string` class, you don't need to (or *want to*) know those details. This concept is known as **encapsulation**, and allows you to seperate **what** a thing does (stores and allows access to a string of characters) from **how** it does it (pointers and length counters, static buffers, or whatever).

In your example:

```
class reff{

public:
     int a;
     int b;
};

reff per;
per.a=36;
```

you directly access the `a` member, but we could write a function which requires a reference to a `reff` object to set the value of its member variable:

```
void setValueA(reff& obj, int value)
{
  obj.a = value;
}
```

and then use similar syntax to the `getline()` method on it:

```
setValueA(per, 36);
```

to achieve the same thing as `per.a = 36`, but with the benefits of encapsulation: if you later need to change the details of how `reff` stores its data (e.g. changing `a` and `b` to meaningful names), you only need to change the function implementation to use the new data members; all user code using this class will continue to work. If user code directly accessed the members, it would also need to be changed to use the new name.

Notice that `setValueA()` is accessing the member variables of the object it is passed; so calling it with `per.a` directly is not only unnecessary, but impossible:

```
setValueA(per.a, 36); // invalid: setValueA() requires a reff&, not an int
```

since the function itself tries to utilise the member `a` of the object it is passed, and an `int` does not have any members.

---

For the `getline()` call using a `std::string`, it has the same issue: for this function to work, it needs at the minimum:

1. read/write access to a pointer to the memory to store the data it reads (it may need to reallocate this if there's not enough space already allocated); and
2. the amount of memory pointed to the above, so it knows how much additional data it can store before it needs to allocate additional space.

So, given that `getline()` requires more than just a single intrinsic type in order to function, it should be clear why the parameter includes a `string object` rather than one of its specific member variable.

---

For additional examples, you should look up [operator overloading](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_overloading.htm), which can even let you do things like have `per = 36;` assign a value to `per.a`.

Here's a self-contained example using overloaded operators on a slightly modified version of your `reff` class. The comments try to explain what's going on, and should give you terms you can search for - this stuff is all pretty basic C++ and should be covered in any tutorial series.

```
#include <iostream>

class Reff
{
public:
    int a;
    float b; // changed the data type to illustrate overloading the = operator

    // operator= will be called if we try to assign to a an object of this class;
    // this version of the function accepts an integer value
    Reff& operator= (int intval)
    {
            a = intval;
            return *this;
    }

    // another operator=, this one accepting a float value as the parameter
    Reff& operator= (float floatval)
    {
            b = floatval;
            return *this;
    }
};

// operator+ will be called if we try to add a value to this object;
// I'm only defining this one which accepts an int value
int operator+ (Reff const& reff, int intval)
{
    return reff.a + intval;
}

// an overload of the operator<< function, which accepts a reference to
// an instance of a Reff, along with the output stream parameter.
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, Reff const& reff)
{
    return stream << "[a:" << reff.a << " b:" << reff.b << "]";
}


int main()
{
    // create an instance of our class
    Reff per;

    // assign the instance 42 (an integer value) - this will use the integer
    // overload of the operator= we defined
    per = 42;

    // assign it a floating point value - this will use the float overload
    // of the operator=. Note that if we didn't define a float-specific overload,
    // the compiler would probably truncate the value to an integer and use our
    // integer version instead - possibly with a warning, possibly silently,
    // depending on your compiler settings.
    per = 3.14159f;

    // output the object; this will use the overload of the operator<< function
    // that we created, which accepts our Reff object
    std::cout << per << std::endl;

    // output the result of adding 58 to our object; this will use the operator+
    // overload which accepts an integer
    std::cout << "per + 58 = " << (per + 58) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Ok so what about this cin>>mystr;

Comment: @Harshul it's the same thing, the `>>` operator has an overload that accepts a reference to a string object. Although the syntax looks quite different, `cin >> mystr` is still just a function call.

Comment: @Harshul - I've added another section to my answer with a small example program showing how to define and use operator overloading within your own class. This might help make it clearer how classes like `std::string` actually work.

Comment: Ok so its all about defining the operators to suit our convinience

Answer (score 1):

Here you can get output directly through

```
cout << "I like " << mystr << " too!\n";
```

because `operator <<` is overridden in `string` Class.

like:

```
ostream& operator << (ostream& OS, MyString & S)
{
    OS << S.get_string();
    return OS;
}
```

Check whole implementation : http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/15396/

Comment: That is not an answer to the question.  That is an explanation of an error in the question (in the choice of examples to illustrate the question).  It was clear what the question was asking, even though the examples were wrong.